# How to return the index of a character in string on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, string, indexing

I want to split a few strings whose separate marks are different.

e.g.separate a string: "A-B^C~D"

So I want to get the index of each separate mark. Is there any method like indexOf(' ') on iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSString have a bunch of methods for finding characters and substrings. They are basically variants of these two:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfCharacterFromSet:(NSCharacterSet *)aSet

- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```

The returned NSRange have a `location` and `length` field. If it couldn't find part `location` will be set to `NSNotFound`

But it looks like you should use the method

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)separator
```

That will return an array with the separated parts.

Answer (score 2):

This code will return the position of the character in the string.

```
NSString *myString = @"A-B^C~D";
int dash = [myString rangeOfString:@"-"].location;
int power = [myString rangeOfString:@"^"].location;
int squiggle = [myString rangeOfString:@"~"].location;
```